# Advantages and disadvantages of having composite primary key

Tags: t-sql

Instead of having a composite primary key (this table maintains the relationship between the two tables which represents two entities [two tables]), the design is proposed to have `identity` column as primary key and the unique data constraint is enforced over two columns which represents the data from the primary key of entities.

For me having identity column for each relationship table is breaking the normalisation rules.

- What is the industry standards?
- What are the considerations to make before making the design decision on this?
- Which approach is right?

Comment: Simple article on the pro's of composite keys:  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

Comment: no need for an identity column, primary key is basically a set of columns (1 or more) that uniquely define your data. By adding an identity column, you are adding an extra index, and making the index you'll probably be using the most (that with the 2 important columns) as non clustered, plus updates/inserts will be a tad slower, etc. etc.  Basically, no need.

Comment: @RThomas - In that weblog, they're using a Customers->Products relationship which shouldn't have a composite key since it indicates transactional data. There *can* be multiple relationships created at different times, that table needs a Unique Identity PKey.
eg, ordering bottles of wine, under the same SKU - referenced by a single ProductID - (not ideal, but possible).
But, if each bottle has it's own ID, then "order limit" is moot since you must create a separate transaction record for each item. Either you've built the structure wrong, or you're tracking data incorrectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of tables where you may want to have an identity column as a primary key. However, in the case of a M:M relationship table you describe, best practice is NOT to use a new identity column for the primary key.

RThomas's link in his comment provides the excellent reasons why the best practice is to NOT add an identity column. Here's [that link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx).

The cons will outweigh the pros in pretty much every case, but since you asked for pros and cons I put a couple of unlikely pros in as well.

**Cons**

- Adds complexity
- Can lead to duplicate relationships unless you enforce uniqueness on the relationship (which a primary key would do by default).
- Likely slower: db must maintain two indexes rather than one.

**Pros**

*All the pros are pretty sketchy*

- If you had a situation where you needed to use the primary key of the relationship table as a join to a separate table (e.g. an audit table?) the join would likely be faster. (As noted though--adding and removing records will likely be slower. Further, if your relationship table is a relationship between tables that themselves use unique IDs, the speed increase from using one identity column in the join vs two will be minimal.)
- The application, for simplicity, may assume that every table it works with has a unique ID as its primary key. (That's poor design in the app but you may not have control over it.) You could imagine a scenario where it is better to introduce some extra complexity in the DB than the extra complexity into such an app.

Comment: The answer is to use both - always have an Identity that is unique on every table [this has more than purely performance based benefits/detriments - programmers have to work with these structures and it's important to have a *consistent methodology for interacting with data*], but use composite keys where it makes sense to do so! And above all, be consistent in your database architecture.

Answer (score 2):

**Cons:**

- Composite primary keys have to be imported in all referencing tables.
  That means larger indexes, and more code to write (e.g. the joins,
  the updates). If you are systematic about using composite primary
  keys, it can become very cumbersome.
- You can't update a part of the primary key. E.g. if you use
  university_id, student_id as primary key    in a table of university
  students, and one student changes    university, you have to delete
  and recreate the record.

**Pros:**

- Composite primary keys allow to enforce a common kind of constraint
  in a powerful and seemless way. Suppose you have a table UNIVERSITY,
  a table STUDENT, a table COURSE, and a table STUDENT_COURSE (which
  student follows which course). If it is a constraint that you always
  have to be a student of university A in order to follow a course of
  university A, then that constraint will be automatically validated if
  university_id is a part of the composite keys of both STUDENT and
  COURSE.

Comment: Re *"Composite primary keys have to be imported in all referencing tables."* Good point - helps clarify when it is worth adding an identity key. For example, consider a table with composite primary key that is N:N pair, plus a small number of additional columns. And no other tables "reference" those composite keys. If design later evolves to add another table with additional info associated with some N:N pairs, at that time it is worth considering adding an identity column to the N:N table, so that the new table only need refer to that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create all the columns in each tables wherever it is used as foreign key. This is the biggest disadvantage.